# How to avoid timeouts when migrating isElementPresent() from Selenium 1 to Selenium 2?

Tags: java, selenium, migration, webdriver, integration-testing

I am trying to migrate Java code from Selenium 1 (RC) to Selenium 2 (WebDriver) that looks something like this:

```
1:  selenium.click(someButton);
2:  selenium.waitForPageToLoad();
3:  if (!selenium.isElementPresent(errorMessageElement)) {
4:     Assert.fail("Test failed! No error msg should be displayed on page.");
5:  }
```

The critical part is line 3, which I tried to translate to Selenium 2 according to advice by [Rostislav Matl](http://rostislav-matl.blogspot.ch/2011/03/moving-to-selenium-2-on-webdriver-part.html) :

```
3:  if (!driver.findElements(By.xpath(errorMessageElement)).size() > 0) {
```

Unfortunately, WebDriver waits for an entire timeout (in my case 60 seconds) to detect that the element really does **not** exist. Although this works, it introduces way too much time overhead...

Is there any way in Selenium 2 to time-efficiently check whether an element is present or absent on the HTML page that is currently displayed in the Web browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is a two part answer

1. **The time overhead is right**: As you would want to make sure that the element is really not rendered. That is, taking the page rendering time, AJAX elements etc in account. I understand that the error message would be displayed along with the page load, but timeout is useful in case you want to check presence (or absence) of ajax elements which get displayed with few milisecond delay.
2. **Hack to reduce wait overhead**: You can nevertheless create a method to temporarily reset the implicit wait time like this

```java
public boolean isElementNotPresent(By by) {
    boolean flag = true;
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    if (!driver.findElements(by).size() > 0) {
        flag = false;
    } 
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    return flag;
}
```

and call this method where you want to check the absence, say for example the 3rd and 4th line would be

```java
if (!isElementNotPresent(By.xpath(xpathoferrorelement))) {
    Assert.fail("Test failed! No error msg should be displayed on page.");
}
```

Comment: This will take only two seconds in ensuring absence of the element found.

Comment: IsElementNotPresent? Wouldn't it be better called IsElementPresent?

Comment: LOL... Yeah you may call it that or whatever you like... but here is the logic ... method will return false if element is present and true if its not .. so 'isElementNotPresent'.... ;)

Comment: Thanks for your idea. Would it make sense to use driver.getPageSource() and then search for the name of the element in it?

Comment: @Dominik, no, that is a very bad idea, more so because you are not verifying that is not present to the user (only that it is rendered on the page), but also it will be very slow shifting through an entire page source.

Comment: how can i get the current value of 'implicitWait' so that i can avoid setting a hardcoded 60?

Answer (score 1):

Try using FluentWait Class, it is easy to configure for conditions that you would like to use:
http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.html

Answer (score 0):

couple approaches that I usually use (to verify present or absent) when the page has been already rendered. 
approach 1:

```
input.findElements(By.xpath("//xpath")).size() > 0
```

approach 2:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(propertyKeysLoader(key))).isDisplayed()
```

approach 3:

```
public bool IsElementPresent(By selector)
{
    return driver.FindElements(selector).Any();
}
```

if you wanna get element rendered (in case you got not all AJAX on the page)  then you'd better use fluent wait as Arek mentioned.

```
 public WebElement fluentWait(final By locator){
        Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
                .withTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .pollingEvery(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

        WebElement foo = wait.until(
new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
            public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
                        return driver.findElement(locator);
                }
                }
);
                           return  foo;              }     ;
```

in the string `.pollingEvery(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)` you can set any iterative timeout . it is  comfortable.
hope this somehow helps you)